# Sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I am unable to understand this error.

I have an object with these properties

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double width;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double height;
```

When I am creating an NSSdictionary add adding them into it

```
   if (config.width) {
        properties[@"height"] = config.height;
    }
    if (config.height) {
        properties[@"height"] = config.height;
    }
```

I am getting following error

> Sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nullable'

If I am correct, type `id` is equivalent to any? which includes `double`. Also, I am setting value if it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am correct, type id is equivalent to any? which includes double

But you're *not* correct. `id` is equivalent to any *object* (an NSObject subclass). `double` is not an object; it's a primitive.

Comment: Once again I offer you http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html. It's free to read and it teaches you Objective-C. Wouldn't learning be better than thrashing?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone wants to know how I was able to fix it, I did

`[NSNumber numberWithDouble:config.height];`